# :first-child fails when an element of a different class is dynamically inserted above

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

So, I've encountered a situation where inserting an element of a different class/id breaks all css-rules on that :first-child.

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
</div>


.nSub:first-child { margin-top:15px; -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px; /* ... */ }
.nSub             { background:#666; /* ... */ }
.nSub:last-child  { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px; /* ... */ }
```

As soon as I insert an element of another class/id above, like this:

```
$('nav').insert({top:'<div id="newWF"></div>'});
```

all declarations for .nSub:first-child are being ignored in both FF 3.6 and Safari 4.

**EDIT:**
sorry if I did not say it clearly: the element inserted above is supposed to NOT have the classname ".nSub"

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="newWF"></div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div> <!-- BROKEN CSS -->
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
    <div class="nSub">abcdef</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the first element with class `nSub` is no longer the `first-child` of the parent, and thus the style no longer matches.

If the dynamically inserted element would also have class `nSub`, then the rule would still match, and match for the newly inserted element (which is now the first child).

I'm no CSS3 expert, but you could try the `:nth-of-type` selector:

```
.nSub:nth-of-type(1) {
   /* Rules for the first .nSub here */
}
```

Comment: The element which was the first-child of the class .nSub before inserting another element (with another class/id!) is afterwards technically still the first element with the class .nSub.

Comment: True, but the pseudo-selector :first-child will only match the first child of an element, it does not consider classes and so on. So when you say .XYZ:first-child, you are saying "Match the first child of an element, where the first child also has the class XYZ"

Comment: So, when I insert an element with another class/id above, my selector cannot match the .nSub element? By the way, I get the same result when using :nth-of-type(1).

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you don't set the class for this inserted element, I guess...

In you CSS-File you say ".nSub:first-child", but the element you are inserting is not of that class: "

Maybe it helps, if you add the class-attribute to that element, too:

```
$('nav').insert({top:'<div id="newWF" class="nSub"></div>'});
```

Comment: It's supposed to be another element.

Comment: I think you didn't get me right. the element #newWF is supposed to not look like the .nSub elements.

Comment: Yepp you are right, I got the wrong unterstanding of your problem. Unfortunately I have no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

What PatrikAkerstrand said about the rule no longer matching is correct. The :first-child pseudo (unfortunately) only targets the first child of its parent that also has the element/class/whatever you specified.

I just spent half an hour cursing at why the following wouldn't work

```
<div id="header">
  <a href="."><img src="path/file.png" /></a>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>

#header .img {
  margin:0 25px;
}
#header .img:first-child,
#header .img:last-child {
  margin:0;
}
```

I found that the solution were to wrap the div.img's into a div.images, like this

```
<div id="header">
  <a href="."><img src="path/file.png" /></a>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</div>

#header .images .img {
  margin:0 25px;
}
#header .images .img:first-child,
#header .images .img:last-child {
  margin:0;
}
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to add non-semantic workaround markup, you can use the :first-of-type pseudo-class. This, however, is not supported in earlier versions of IE.